# Matlab :Error in Curve fitting

Tags: matlab, optimization, curve-fitting, estimation

I have described a model and i would like to fit in the Curve,I am obtaining an Error in this context , kindly review it.

```
function c = model(t, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, td, tmax)

c = zeros(size(t));

ind = (t > td) & (t < tmax);
c(ind) = (t(ind) - td) ./ (tmax - td) * (a1 + a2 + a3);

ind = (t >= tmax);
c(ind) = a1 * exp(-b1 * (t(ind) - tmax))+ a2 * exp(-b2 * (t(ind) - tmax)) + a3 * exp(-b3 * (t(ind) - tmax));




ft = fittype('model(t, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, td, tmax)', 'independent','t');
fo = fit(t, c, ft,'StartPoint', [20000, 20000, 20000, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 10, 30],'Lower', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
plot(t, c, 'x')
hold all
ts = 0:0.1:50;
plot(ts, model(ts, fo.a1, fo.a2, fo.a3, fo.b1, fo.b2, fo.b3, fo.td, fo.tmax))
axis([0 50 -2000 80000])
xlabel time
ylabel concentration    

end
```

Following is the error i am obtaining

```
Error in fittype expression ==> model(t, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, td, tmax)
??? Expression model(t, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, td, tmax) is not a valid MATLAB
expression,
 has non-scalar coefficients, or cannot be evaluated:
```

Could you please review if i have used fittype expression correctly

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that holds the model:

```
function c = modelfnc(t, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, td, tmax)
...    
end
```

Then put the rest of the code in the main function (another file). Also you need to define the variables and have some data before starting the fitting process.

```
define c,t,...
ft = fittype('modelfnc(t, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, td, tmax)', 'independent','t');
fo = fit(t, c, ft,'StartPoint', [20000, 20000, 20000, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 10, 30],'Lower', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
plot(t, c, 'x')
```