# Error with fitting a model in Matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a model to data with 3 variables and 4 paramters as follows (following [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fittype.html#btpaend-11) Matlab example):

```matlab
ft = fittype(@(a,b,c,d,x,y,z) a*(x.^b).*(y.^c).*(z.^d),...
 'independent',{'x','y','z'},'dependent',{'w'},'coefficients',...
{'a','b','c','d'})
```

where `a, b, c` and `d` need to be evaluated for given data of `x,y,z`. But Matlab gives me an error and doesn't allow me to create a `fittype` object. The error reads :

```
Expression @(a,b,c,d,x,y,z) a*(x.^b).*(y.^c).*(z.^d) is not a valid MATLAB expression, has non-scalar coefficients, or cannot be evaluated:
Not enough inputs to FITTYPE function.
```

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360239/matlab-error-in-curve-fitting) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805885/how-can-i-use-fittype-function-to-define-a-custom-equation) question on StackOverflow but didn't fully understand where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use this type it will be execute command ;

```
ft = fittype(@(a,b,c,x,y) a*(x.^b).*(y.^c),...
 'independent',{'x','y'},'dependent',{'w'},'coefficients',...
{'a','b','c'})
```

In your type of command, there is too much expression which cannot be processed by Matlab. 'Independent' section of the fittype fucntion only takes 1 pair.

Comment: then what is the alternative in Matlab ?